# Search GeoPoints from an array of points

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to search whether a given GeoPoint is within a given radius provided with the users current location in Android. Are there any methods like containsLatLang() method in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5b%5d%29), standard android API lets you calculate the distance between two points. Should be enough for you to do your check.